# Python GAE Problems Sending Email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying out GAE and having a little trouble sending email from my application in both development and production. I understand the development server needs a little configuration first, but production should be send email. There are no errors that I can see viewing the console (I start the server via terminal window), and none reported in the production application.

The code:

```
def contactSend():
message = mail.EmailMessage()
message.sender = "myaddress@gmail.com"
message.to = "myaddress@gmail.com"
message.subject = "Test email from python"
message.body = "This is the test"
message.send()
```

What I have checked so far: 
Code appears to be correct.
-Sender (and to) address have administrator level permissions of the project.
-Project is configured as Python 2.7 (some issues on 2.5 I guess).
-My spam folder.

I'm sure I'm likely missing something simple as I'm very new to GAE. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've also tried mail.sendmail:

```
mail.send_mail(sender="myaddress@gmail.com",
          to="myaddress@gmail.com",
          subject="This is the test 1124pm",
          body="TEST!")
```

No luck there either. Possible that I need to register a domain or set up a Google Apps account maybe?

Edit2 11:52am: I've tried a check_valid_email to be sure and that came back true. I saw the "send_mail_to_admins" function and gave that a shot assuming it might be less restricting and possibly work, but nothing there either.

Edit3: I don't know if it helps but here's the request handler:

```
class contactSend(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        contactSend()
        self.response.out.write("sent! ")
```

Comment: Are you running dev server with --enable_sendmail option?

Comment: Yes, good question. I'm also running each test in a live application on GAE just to be sure.

Comment: I just tried again using the email address, "myprojectname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" but nothing there either. Both dev and live.

Comment: Are you sure that the sender address in registered a admin or dev in the gae console? The sender address must be registered or logged in, you can't use any sender address.

Comment: Does your `app.yaml` have: 
`libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest`

Comment: AHH! OK get this - they showed up in my spam folder with a date of Sept 29th! I haven't touched this since the 22nd. I'm going to call this a Google problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippets appear to be correct (with the exception of improper indentation of your first function), so I'm going to provide some debugging information to help you solve your problem.

1. Check the Logs of your application to see if any exceptions are being raised by your code which may prevent things from working as intended.
   https://appengine.google.com/logs?&app_id=**YOUR_APP_ID**
2. Check the Quota Details of your application to see if any emails have been sent.
   https://appengine.google.com/dashboard/quotadetails?&app_id=**YOUR_APP_ID**
3. Ensure the `sender` email address has accepted the App Engine invite and is not listed as "pending" on the Permissions page.
   https://appengine.google.com/permissions?&app_id=**YOUR_APP_ID**
4. Double-check the `to` and `sender` email addresses. Copy/paste them and try to send an email to them directly through the email application of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! My log just looks like this over an over: /contactsend 200 14ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36

Comment: Checking main quota - everything is at 0. So nothing actually triggered.

Comment: The problem *might* be that your `RequestHandler` is named `contactSend` and you call `contactSend()` as a function within it.
You can't name them both the same thing.  
Try changing the function name **or** handler name to something different.

Comment: @JacobM. Did this answer help you with your question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to send e-mails from a certain address, you need to set up a domain first, and grant access to the application to send e-mails using it.

If you don’t want/need to set up a domain, and if you application requires log in, you could simply use:

```
mail.send_mail(sender=users.get_current_user().email(),
      to="myaddress@gmail.com",
      subject="This is the test 1124pm",
      body="TEST!")
```